# Why do we need (a simple version of) Bertini's theorem to find isolated solutions of an overdetermined polynomial system?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand how overdetermined systems of polynomials are handled. The method outlined in the book numerically solving polynomial systems with Bertini, is that of randomization. If we have an overdermined system $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ in $m$ variables where $n>m$. We take a random matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and look at the new system $Af$. The claim this book makes is that all isolated solutions of $f$ will also be isolated solutions of $Af$ and this is guaranteed with probability one by a simple version of Bertini's theorem.

> Suppose that $f_1(z),\ldots,f_n(z)$ are polynomials defined on a non-empty Zariski open subset $U$ of an irreducible affine complex algebraic set $X\subset \mathbb{C}^m$ with the property that given any point $x\in U$, there is at least one $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $f_i(x)\neq 0$. Then there is a nonempty Zariski open subset $V\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ such that for $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\in V$, $f_\lambda(z) = \lambda_1f_1(z)+\dots+\lambda_nf_n(z)$ has the property that $f_\lambda^{-1}(0)$ is either empty or smooth of pure dimension $m-1$, i.e.,
>
> $Z(f_\lambda(z))$ is empty or of pure dimension $m-1$ and
>
> $Z(f_\lambda(z),\dfrac{\partial f_\lambda(z)}{\partial z_1},\ldots, \dfrac{\partial f_\lambda(z)}{\partial z_m}) = \emptyset$.

I am not sure how to translate this theorem in terms of isolated solutions. And hence I do not know why this would imply isolated solutions of $f$ are isolated solutions of $Af$.

Comment: I found a post asking a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233716/question-about-squaring-up-a-system-of-polynomial-equations. As far as I can tell the authors included this theorem just so they could mention where the name of their software package comes from. Since the claim which is made can be solved using a lot simpler methods.